# Why does my android app restarts when I put it out of the dockingstation?

Tags: android

Hy
I wrote my own Android App. My problem is, that it restarts everytime I put it out of my docking station.
what can i do?

best regards
markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is, that it restarts everytime I put it out of my docking station

Putting a device in or out of supported car and desk docks results in a [configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), the same as if the user rotates the screen, changes a locale, attaches a keyboard, etc.

So, your app does not restart, but your activity is destroyed and recreated, by default.

> what can i do?

Support configuration changes, via `onSaveInstanceState()`, retained fragments, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to override the configuration change when a tablet/phone is docked?

Comment: @Marche101: You can add `android:configChanges` to your manifest to tell Android not to destroy and recreate the activities. However, since you *still* need to support other types of configuration changes (screen rotations, locale changes, etc.), it would be simpler for you to not treat dock changes specially, but just support configuration changes correctly in general.

Comment: So far this is what I am doing. I am handling orientation changes myself but the app is still destroyed when I dock/undock the device. I am also handling a lot of data that takes a long time to read from the disk (many bitmaps) and so I cannot hold them in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() for the destroyed activity.

Comment: @Marche101: "so I cannot hold them in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() for the destroyed activity" -- nonsense. The only way that would be possible is if you could never load the data in the first place, which apparently is not the case.